# How to test if an Elixir (or erlang) value can be written as binary

Tags: erlang, elixir

I think this question is the same as asking how do I check if a value is an `io_list`. I want this to be as efficient as possible, therefore do not want to turn the value into a binary as part of the process of checking if it is an io_list.

Comment: I don't think there's any function to check this, but I believe calling `iolist_size/1` on the value and catching `ArgumentError` should be pretty fast. If it raises `ArgumentError`, it's not a valid iolist.

Comment: No matter what you do, to check if the thing is an io_list the system will have to iterate over every element in the (possible) io_list. You should never *not know* what data your own program has generated. If it is code from an untrusted source, you must validate it *anyway* and from that point on should know. The real answer here is to use Dialyzer at compile time, not do a runtime check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing the stdlib of Erlang, I believe your best choice is to use `:erlang.iolist_size` and catch `ArgumentError` to detect invalid iolists.

```
iolist? = fn x ->
  try do
    :erlang.iolist_size(x)
    true
  rescue
    ArgumentError -> false
  end
end

IO.inspect iolist?("foo")
IO.inspect iolist?(["foo"])
IO.inspect iolist?(:foo)
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

In my highly unscientific benchmark, this is about thrice as fast as `:erlang.iolist_to_binary/1`.

```
iolist = List.duplicate([[[1, "2"], '3'], ?4], 1000000)
IO.inspect :timer.tc(:erlang, :iolist_to_binary, [iolist])
IO.inspect :timer.tc(:erlang, :iolist_size, [iolist])
```

```
{82291,
 <<1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1,
   50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1,
   50, 51, 52, 1, 50, 51, 52, 1, ...>>}
{25577, 4000000}
```